# Browse Wikimedia Commons images by date

Tags: search, wikimedia-commons, gallery

I want to find pictures of China taken in the 1930~1940 in the [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) gallery.

Is there an app that would allow me to do that?

For instance I would select a date range (like 1930~1940), and filter by a category (like "China").

Results must be presented as a gallery of thumbnails.

Comment: You do know that you can just [click through to country by year](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:1930_in_China)? There's your gallery.

Comment: Seeing all images on a page would be more convenient than clicking through all 20 years and all of its sub-categories, but that's better than nothing indeed, feel free to propose as an answer :-)